# Where can I find a guidebook of Menorca?

Tags: spain, islands, guidebooks

I'm looking for a guidebook to visit Menorca. For other travels I used to get the "Lonely Planet" guide, but there isn't any of Menorca, and I think that get one of "Spain" is too wide.

Where I can find a good guide of Menorca?

Comment: Hmm other questions using the [tag:guides] tag I thought were about human guides. I wonder if we should differentiate with [tag:guidebook] or if recommendations are too off topic generally to want one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [Eyewitness Travel Guides](http://traveldk.com/) by DK. They have a [Mallorca, Menorca & Ibiza](http://www.dorlingkindersley-uk.co.uk/nf/Book/BookDisplay/0,,9781405353137,00.html?strSrchSql=mallorca/DK_Eyewitness_Travel_Guide%3a_Mallorca,_Menorca_&_Ibiza) book.

Comment: There are also "Time Out: Mallorca And Menorca", "The Rough Guide to Mallorca and Menorca", "Frommer's Mallorca and Menorca Day By Day". Generally if you like Lonely Planet, Rough Guide is designed to appeal to exactly the same audience. Other guides may target somewhat different audiences but I haven't tried them all. Wikitravel is a good internet guidebook.

Answer (score 4):

I find "[Menorca Berlitz Pocket Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812683739)" to be a good option, is pretty extensive, has very usefull information and is not expensive.

One good place to start looking for interesting places in Menorca is http://www.travelmenorca.co.uk/guide/index.htm, it's not very extensive, it only give short descriptions, but is a good start point.

**Some interesting things about Menorca:**

There are phenomenal beaches, specially the coves that in Menorca are named “Cala ….”. Some of these coves are amazing places, I especially liked “Cala Macarella” and the adjacent cove “Cala Macarelleta” (Macarelleta is a diminutive of Macarella) that’s a smaller cove adjacent to the main Cove. There is a beautiful footpath between the two coves (bordering the sea over a cliff).

One important thing about Menorca coves is that many of them have parking for cars and motorcycles a few hundred meters away from the cove, so you will have to walk a little, but this is not the most important thing, the important fact is that when that parking is full they don’t allow more people on the cove, so if you want to go to a concrete cove, go early on the morning or you have very good chances of not being able to accomplish your goal.
Another important thing about Menorca is that the roads to the coves and beaches use to be very narrow, so if you plan to rent a car, rent a little one.

And last but not least, if you like to eat fish you MUST go to “Fornells” (a little fishing village on the north coast of the island) and order a “[Caldereta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobster_stew)”.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, there may not be a Lonely Planet **book** for Menorca, but their website contains a write-up for it:

[Introducing Menorca - Menorca Travel Information and Travel Guide - Spain - Lonely Planet.](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/spain/balearic-islands/menorca)

[image]

Comment: And you can get just the Mallorca/Menorca/Ibiza chapter of the Spain Book: http://shop.lonelyplanet.com/spain/spain-travel-guide/spain-mallorca-menorca-and-ibiza-chapter-8/